# why <<\END is used in ed

Tags: here-document, passwd, ed

Using `ed` put character `#` to the beginning of lines 10 to 20 in file `/etc/passwd`.
Solution is the following

```
ed /etc/passwd <<\END
10,20s/^/#/
%p
Q
END
```

my question is that what does `<<` means here and `\` before `END` and why we use it. Do we have to use it all the time or not?

Answer (score 4):

What you are showing is `ed` being used together with an editing script.

The editing script (a series of `ed` commands) is being passed into `ed` as a here-document.  A here-document is a piece of possibly multi-line text *redirected* into the standard input of a utility. The here-document is what's between the first and last `END` markers.  The `\` in front of the first `END` marker means that the document is quoted, meaning that the shell will not try to expand variables etc. in it.  It could also have been written as `<<'END'`.  In this specific instance, the `\` can be removed since the editing script does not contain anything for the shell to expand.

This is a common way to use `ed` for simpler non-interactive editing, although `ed` should be used with its `-s` option when using it in this way.

The command is equivalent in effect to using `sed` with

```
sed '10,20/^/#/' /etc/passwd
```

(The `ed` script will make the changes in the file and then display the file in the terminal before exiting *without* saving the changes, which is more or less what the above `sed` script is doing on a line-by-line basis).

---

This is *not* a good way of editing the `/etc/passwd` file though (which the `ed` script is actually not doing, thankfully, since it doesn't save its changes).  For that, tools like `vipw` or specific commands made for modifying this file (like `useradd` etc.) should be used. This is because the file, on many Unix systems, needs to be in sync with one or several other files or databases, and editing it requires updating these too (which e.g. `vipw` does automatically).

Comment: @SomiaMonawar Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

It's not `ed`, it's your shell.

It means take raw input until the word `END` and send it to the `STDIN` of a command.

For example:

```
$ cat <<\END
> something
> END
something
```

produces the same result as:

```
$ echo something | cat
something
```

Comment: The result may not always be the same depending on the use of quotes in the `something` string.  Consider, for example the string `"hello"`.

Comment: It is the same if you quote/escape properly, which is half the reason to use the `<<\END` feature, so you don't have to worry about it. The shell is just passing the contents of the quotes to echo when you run `echo "something"`, you could of course wrap it in singles to pass the double quotes to echo: `echo '"something"' | cat` or just escape the double quotes `echo \"something\" | cat`