# cut and paste in ed

Tags: ed

Can someone tell me that how we do cut and paste in `ed`, for example for the following question?

> Write a script for `ed` which moves all lines starting with character `#` to the end of the input file?

Comment: Is this homework? I suggest reading the `man`page for `ed`, trying with what you've learned, and editing your questiin with where you are having trouble if you can't get it to work.

Comment: i tried for /etc/passwd as ed /etc/passwd <<\END

Answer (score 4):

This question is worded like a homework question.  You will learn very little by having the answer given to you.

> `g/^#/m$`
>
>
> This applies the move-to-end command (`m$`) to all lines matching `/^#/`.  All that is missing is to write the result back to the original file. For an extra challenge, combine this with [your last question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437553/why-end-is-used-in-ed) and come up with a way of commenting out line 10 through to 20 *and* move them to the end of the file, not touching other commented out lines.